Anchor points on scroll and sticky header overlapping headline on content
I have the next structure:

So I have a header... in the top of the page, that header is sticky as the anchor point menu at the left and in addition, the header it is hidden and it is shown when making scroll, when it makes scroll down and it is hidden, and when the scroll goes up it is shown.  I explain that so you can understand the whole problem.
So what is happening currently is, that when I click any of the links in the left menu, trying to going up, the header overlaps the content, in this case the headlines, who are the ones who contains the anchor point inside the text.
See example here

The left side menu was having the same issue, but I manage to partially fix it by using
.header[data-visible="true"]~main {
  .container {
    &__side-menu {
      @include phone {
        top: 100px;
      }

      ul {
        @include tablet {
          top: 230px;
        }
      }
    }

  }

}

So when the header is visible, give more top to the menu, so this work fine. The Problem is when I tried to do similar with the content, doesn't work quite well because the content container have a position: relative, so when tried to apply a margin-bottom for some reason the margin is not being remove, when going doing on scroll(and menu is not visible). So I was wondering if there is an approach and simple with css, with who I can cover both Problems, when not what can you suggest me?

Look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding
